# Expression cannot contain implicitly-typed arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a foreach statement that I generate a collection by splitting up a text file at each "\r\n" or "\n" as follows:

```
foreach (var value in baiTxt.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)){ do work;}
```

When I try to add a Watch on baiTxt.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None) I get the error "Expression cannot contain implicitly-typed arrays.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Well it sounds like that's just a limitation of the watch window. I suggest you just evaluate the expression before the `foreach` loop and assign the result to a local variable: `var values = baiTxt.Split(...); foreach (var value in values) { ... }`. Then you can look at `values` in the debugger.

Comment: Absolutely @JonSkeet, Watch had no protest with the local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code segment.

```
baiTxt.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

for

```
baiTxt.Split(new string[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Thanks, Watch had no problem with your expression.